# Permanently set USB connection mode

Tags: adb, usb-connection-mode, touchscreen, mtp

My phones touchscreen has been gradually failing for a few months, so before it dies completely I rooted it and installed Webkey so I can control it via a browser. Of course that requires the wifi to be on, so what I want to do is plug the phone into my computer and turn on the wifi on from the adb shell (which I've done, and it works fine).
The thing is, adb doesn't see my phone unless I manually set the connection mode to MTP, and I won't be able to do that when the touchscreen goes completely unresponsive.

So, how would I set my phone to automatically use MTP when I connect it via USB?

It's an Alcatel OneTouch 993, running Android 4.0.4.

Comment: Why not just leave the Wi-Fi turned on?

Comment: To save on the battery.

Comment: What about other ways to trigger WiFi? I think e.g. of using *Tasker* to toggle WiFi. Possible toggles (selection): Camera-button, NFC, Bluetooth. Would that be acceptable? Apart from that: Can't the connection-mode be made permanent? Most devices support that ("always use X").

Comment: Thanks, problem solved! I used MacroDroid to turn on the wifi when I shake the phone, which is even easier than using adb :)